# Building Healpy library - can not find cfitsio library

Tags: python, healpy

I am trying to build a Python library Healpy. My first try was to use pip. After typing:

```
>pip install --user healpy
```

i got result:

```
>checking if library 'cfitsio' is installed
>error: No such file or directory
```

After that i tried to build library on my own - i downloded the sources and builded cfitsio using commands:

```
>/.configure
>make
>make install
```

after doing that i got a `libcfitsio.a` file, `pkg-config` folder with .pc file and some .h files in include folder. But after typing:

```
> python setup.py install
```

i got the same error. I got the same error after building lib in Windows. Did anyone have similar problem ? I would be very greateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have `libcfitsio.a` in the place where compiler can find it?

Comment: I guess the path are not set up properly. For cfitsio check `./configure [--prefix=/target/installation/path]` and specify the `/target/installation/path` which depends on your os.

Comment: @greole
i have tried to add a --prefix=/### before and it didnt work. what do you mean path depends on your os ? i am using windows ( tries in linux were conducted using Cygwin and in this case i set the prefix to /user/lib )

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [healpy INSTALL documentation](https://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) you must specify the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable if you want to use external *cfitsio* or *healpix* modules:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Note: adapt with your own path obtain from the *cfitsio* compilation process!

Then you shall be able to run the compilation of healpy...